# Query nested IEnumerable model class - combined model for view has two classes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a combined ViewModel that consists of two nested classes. One is IEnumerable the other isn't. The reason is I want to use both is so in the View I can use @foreach and @Html.DisplayNameFor.    The view is using @model Project.ViewModels.BlogCommentCombinedViewModel

I found a article on how to use nested models, however I'm getting a error trying to use IEnumerable nested class and my LINQ query is presenting "cannot implicity convert type BlogViewModel to Systems.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Project.ViewModels.BlogViewModel>

How do explicitly cast or is there a better way?

Controller

```
    var blogResult = from a in _db.Users
                              join b in _db.blog on a.Id equals b.userID
                              select new BlogCommentCombinedViewModel
                              {
                                  
                                 bvm = new BlogViewModel
                                 { GETTING ERROR HERE:
                                   "cannot implicity convert type BlogViewModel to Systems.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Project.ViewModels.BlogViewModel>" An explicit conversion exist - are you missing a cast
                                 }


                                 lcvm = new LeaveCommentViewModel
                                 {
                                   //binding data in here

                                 }

                              } ;
```

Combined View Model

```
 public class BlogCommentCombinedViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<BlogViewModel> bvm { get; set;}
        public LeaveCommentViewModel lcvm { get; set; }
    }
```

```
    public class BlogViewModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int blogID { get; set; }

        public string blogTitle { get; set; }
        public string blogContent { get; set; }
        public string userID { get; set; }

        public DateTime publishedDate { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public string firstName { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public string lastName { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
```

```
 public class LeaveCommentViewModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int commentID { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Comment")]
        [MinLength(5, ErrorMessage = "Comment is too short")]
        public string comment { get; set; }
        public string reply { get; set; }
        public int blogID { get; set; }
        public string userID { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `IEnumerable<BlogViewModel>` != `BlogViewModel`.  Even though you are only creating a single element, you need to wrap it in an `IEnumerable<BlogViewModel>` - or something which implements that interface, e.g. `List<T>`.

Instead try this:

```cs
// Definition
public class BlogCommentCombinedViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<BlogViewModel> bvm { get; set;}
    public LeaveCommentViewModel lcvm { get; set; }
}

// Query
var blogResult = from a in _db.Users
                 join b in _db.blog on a.Id equals b.userID
                 select new BlogCommentCombinedViewModel
                 {                                  
                     bvm = new[]
                     { 
                         new BlogViewModel() // etc
                     },
                     lcvm = new LeaveCommentViewModel
                     {
                         // binding data in here
                     }
                 };
```

This creates an array of one `BlogViewModel` item - which can be implicitly converted to `IEnumerable<T>`.

### Test code

This compiles and runs in LINQPad:

```cs
var users = new[] { new User(42) };
var blog = new[] { new Blog(42) };

var test = from u in users
           join b in blog on u.Id equals b.UserId
           select new BlogCommentCombinedViewModel
           {
               bvm = new[]
               {
                   new BlogViewModel() // etc
               },
               lcvm = new LeaveCommentViewModel
               {
                   // binding etc
               }
           };

test.Dump();

public record User(int Id);

public record Blog(int UserId);

public class BlogCommentCombinedViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<BlogViewModel> bvm { get; set; }
    public LeaveCommentViewModel lcvm { get; set; }
}

public class BlogViewModel
{
    // etc
}

public class LeaveCommentViewModel
{
    // etc
}
```

Comment: thanks, I've tried your suggestion however I'm getting: InvalidOperationException: The client projection contains a reference to a constant expression of 'Project.BlogViewModel[]'. This could potentially cause a memory leak; consider assigning this constant to a local variable and using the variable in the query instead.

Comment: That sounds like you have an error in the syntax somewhere - I have mocked this up and it compiles fine - I'll add my test code to the answer.  It's not quite the same as yours because I don't have the db connection etc, but the select part should work fine - if you've checked it and it matches but still doesn't work, perhaps you could post what you have and I'll look it over?